# How to create an object that is labeled as something

Tags: python

I'm using python and I want to create a class that has many variables, some of them will be normal variables and others will need to be updated to a server. I have a loop that runs over all the object's variables but I don't know how to identify which variables need to be updated. **I could have those objects as a class with one variable but I would prefer not to.** Is there an acceptable way to achieve this?

I want something like Unity has in its C# library where you can define a regular int like `public int health = 100;` but you can also define it as `[SyncVar] public int health =100;` and then you can use the variable as you normally would except it has that extra data.

The loop that checks the object's variable looks like this:

```
def send_sync_vars(o):    
    for k, v in o.__dict__.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, SyncVar):
            update_var(k ,v)
```

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Does your solution work?

Comment: It does but then when I use the variable I have to check if it is a SyncVar because I need to write var.value instead of just var. It makes using those variables not comfortable and the code look much denser.

Comment: If you're defining your own variables, you can consider using `@property` and `@SyncVar.setter` to help you?

Comment: I've never seen those, could you explain more?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add annotations to attributes like in C#. (Newer versions of python *do* support [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), but those are for, well, *type* annotations. I would advise against abusing them for a different purpose.)

The easiest way label a bunch of attributes as SyncVars is probably to store their names in a class attribute:

```
class MyClass:
    SYNC_VARS = {'foo', 'bar'}

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

def send_sync_vars(o):    
    for k, v in vars(o).items():
        if k in o.SYNC_VARS:
            update_var(k, v)
```

Another possibility would be to over-engineer the whole thing and implement those attributes as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class SyncVar(property):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if fget is None:
            fget = self.default_getter

        if fset is None:
            fset = self.default_setter

        if fdel is None:
            fdel = self.default_deleter

        super().__init__(fget, fset, fdel, *args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def default_getter(self):
        return self._value

    @staticmethod
    def default_setter(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @staticmethod
    def default_deleter(self):
        del self._value

class MyClass:
    foo = SyncVar()
    bar = SyncVar()

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

def send_sync_vars(o):    
    for k, v in vars(type(o)).items():
        if isinstance(v, SyncVar):
            v = getattr(o, k)
            update_var(k, v)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a clear answer, the second possibility is what I'm looking for, I tried to run `def send_sync_vars(o):
    for k, v in vars(type(o)).items():
        if isinstance(v, SyncVar):
            print '%s is a sync var' % k


o1 = MyClass('fooVar', 2, [1, 2, 3])
send_sync_vars(o1)`
but nothing printed, any idea why?

Comment: @Koby27 Not sure, it should work. Did you maybe forget to add the `foo = SyncVar()` assignment *in the class body*?

Comment: @Koby27 Actually, I forgot you're using python 2. I think in python 2 descriptors only work in new-style classes, so let `MyClass` inherit from `object`: `class MyClass(object):`.